# How to add CSS to a TYPO9.5 Extension?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

What is the correct way of adding CSS to the public folder of an extension? What do I need to do in order for that CSS to be loaded in.

For example I have the following structure:

```
Public/Css/style.css
Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript
Configuration/TypoScript/constants.typoscript
```

Would I have to add some code in setup.typoscript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since TYPO3 8.7 you can add HTML to the header or footer from your Fluid template using the `HeaderAssets` and `FooterAssets` sections. For example:

```
<f:section name="HeaderAssets">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{f:uri.resource(path: 'Css/styles.css')}"/>
</f:section>
```

The advantage of this over page.includeCSS is that it is only included whenever that template is rendered, instead of on all pages.

Comment: Does this work with page templates as well as with plugin templates?

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS has to be in:
`extensionkey/Resources/Public/Css/`

And then in your typoscript (setup) you can add:

`page.includeCSS.csskey = EXT:extensionkey/Resources/Public/Css/style.css`

The "csskey" has to be unique identifier.

Comment: and it only works if your `PAGE` object is named `page`, otherwise the usage of that extension needs manual interaction.

Comment: Where would I have to define the page object, what does it require?